# how to build and run the light-portal from light-4j platform

Tags: light-4j

I am a developer from who wants to create an ecosystem around micro services. My research led to your software projects, which are outstanding in many respects.
Unfortunately, one of the components I couldn't get running for an initial review was the portal.
The build failed due to a missing light-4j version (1.5.29).
The light-4j master branch is at 1.5.23, hence I checked out the portal at a version that meets the light-4j version. With this the docker-compose-hybrid.yml script failed, due to other missing libraries. Considering the fact that I even reverted to an older version of the portal sources, I am almost sure that I am on the wrong track.
Do you have any advice for me how to get this solved?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your interest in the light platform. The light-portal is still in heavy development in develop branch which is depending on the develop branch of light-4 and other libraries. The easiest way to build it is through light-bot which is our own DevOps tool for microservices as you can see you are dealing with too many dependencies and most DevOps tools on the market can only deal with one repository each time.

https://github.com/networknt/light-config-test/tree/master/light-bot/develop-build/build-portal

Also, please be aware that light-portal services are built on top of light-hybrid which is a serverless framework. The build process just creates small jar files and copy to the read and write service folders. You need to start a compose to start the two services to load all the services.

The following the docker-compose to start the light-portal locally.

https://github.com/networknt/light-config-test/tree/master/light-portal

I am starting to write a light-portal tutorial but there are still a lot of topics are missing. Please let me know if you see any gaps so that I can add more info into it.

https://doc.networknt.com/tutorial/portal/

The mail might not be the best channel as the communication is on a private channel. In the future, you can ask questions on gitter as other people might know the answer when our team members are not available immediately. Also, the answers on the public channel might help other users to learn the platform.

https://gitter.im/networknt/light-4j